# Ubuntu 20.04 for arm chip

Tags: mac

I'm looking to download Ubuntu 20.04 server for ARM but I can't find it under being redirected from https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Why not try downloading it from Ubuntu, ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm  , fyi: if you're after an older version like 20.04, it's still also easily obtained from that page if you look, eg. I see https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/release/ for links from my first link